# IDE with instant code diff during editing

Tags: windows, ide, diff

I find I work much more efficiently by editing code with previous version of the code next to it (side-by-side comparison).

[image]

So tools like WinMerge aren't uncommon to me.
**I can immediately see what changes I had done on-the-go.**

But, WinMerge and other diff tools are not full featured IDEs. (they don't have auto-completion, refactoring, etc...)

Is there an IDE, which provides "instant" code diff comparison while you're editing the code? I mostly write code in Java for desktops (with Netbeans), and I develop for Android (with Eclipse).